# How to extend the size of my C drive on XP

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

In Windows XP, how do I increase the size of my C drive from other partitions?

I don't see any option in Disk Management and can't figure out how to use Partition Magic for that which I have installed.

Note: My all drives are NTFS.

Comment: My problem was solved by using this great piece of software: http://www.geeksdo.com/extend-c-drive-pc-acronis.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **must** delete the other partition and **consolidate** them as free space just following the Windows partition. Under these conditions, you can enlarge the Widows partition to include the following unused space.

If the Disk Management of XP can't do it (try it first), some free utilities with good graphical interface are:

[EASEUS Partition Master (Home Edition)](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm)
[Paragon Partition Manager Express](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/)

I suggest to take good backups first, as resizing the C: system drive can cause Windows to become unbootable.

Comment: It's not really necessary to delete partitions. GParted f.e. can shrink/resize Partitions and move them around. He could shrink the second one and move it to the end of the harddisk.

Comment: @Bobby: If he wants to keep them.

Comment: Note: The partition number of the Windows partition shouldn't be changed. Meaning that any partition before Windows shouldn't be deleted, or Windows might not boot and require fixing.

Comment: Easeus wouldn't expand it with the free version.  And Paragon Partition Manager wouldn't even run.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use GParted within [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/). It is a Linux based partitioning tool that can boot from CD, USB or network and do almost anything with partitions: resize, move, clone, etc. Works better than Symantec's PartitionMagic for me, and also the interface is much more nicer.

Comment: Please please please please BACKUP FIRST, especially if working with NTFS.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use gparted.  It's never done me wrong, even on Windows partitions (ntfs).  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), it has an easy interface and a beginner friendly documentation.

**Warning**: Backup your data first (just in case), changing partitions *can* result in data loss, I mean 99% of the time it is working flawlessly, but the other 1%...gggrrrrrr. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that still works: https://www.resize-c.com/howto/windows-xp-partition-tool.html

I was resizing a virtual machine, not a real HD so booting into Linux wouldn't have been easy.