# Mount second SSD disc to existing file system

Tags: windows, windows-xp, filesystems, mount

I have a 256GB OS SSD, and another new 256GB SSD, i would like to expand my C:/ partition to this new drive, effectively expanding the C:/ partition to 512GB

Instead of 2x256GB partitions

1x512GB C:/ partition

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: The Question is why would you want to do this? The SSDs need to be the same to do a raid and you would achieve this in the bios. But it would be a stripped array and be less stable even if they are the same drives.

Comment: Reason I do this is to have more disc space on drive C. If I understood correctly I can merge these disks somewhere in bios under raid settings? I was thinking that raid in general is disc data duplication on another disc.

Comment: Why dont you just use Symbolic Links and you would get the same results of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you really running Windows XP?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin, it's possible that SSDs need to be the same in Windows fakeRAID, but I've routinely used disparate drives in hardware RAID arrays and in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a JBOD (just a bunch of disks) or spanned volume. Here is a link to the Technet site describing how to do that:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772180.aspx#BKMK_WINUI

As it states in the first paragraph, this does not work with a system disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a RAID controller in the PC, then you can do this by setting the drives up as a RAID 0 (striped) volume. The RAID controller will present the pair of disks to the OS as one disk.

Major issues with this approach:
You can't EXPAND onto this. You'd have to wipe and reload.

If EITHER drive develops problems, you lose the ENTIRE filesystem. Make sure you have good backups

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Hardware RAID.  You can stripe both drives into one volume. You will need to reinstall if you use windows. If one disk dies then you loose all the data.
2. Some software RAIDs also allow this. But you also need to reinstall.
3. Or use them as two separate disks. Note that you do not need to add the second disk as a new volume.  You can simply mount it in a folder. This is trivial to do from windows diskmanagement.
4. Or use them as two separate disks (with a volume letter) and links or junction folders to it.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions assume you are comfortable performing advanced computer tasks.

1. Get [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and put on USB stick
2. Use CloneZilla to save your entire C:\ drive to an external hard drive or giant USB stick
3. Add second SSD to system
4. Go into BIOS and set up RAID 0 - **THIS WILL WIPE ALL DATA**
5. Use CloneZilla to restore WinXP to the "C:\" drive
6. Use a partitioning tool to reclaim new 256GB SSD space

Read:

[How to extend the size of my C drive on XP](https://superuser.com/questions/100217/how-to-extend-the-size-of-my-c-drive-on-xp)

http://www.disk-partition.com/resource/extend-and-shrink-xp-partition.html

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dm_extend_basic_volume.mspx?mfr=true