# How do I extend my C drive when my drive is like this?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I can't edit the WINRE partition between my C and D drive, and I can't re-order my partitions.
Is there a way to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend the size of my C drive on XP](https://superuser.com/questions/100217/how-to-extend-the-size-of-my-c-drive-on-xp)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after using a third party program.
Here's what you need to do if you also have this problem:

1. Delete your D drive space, turning it into unallocated space
2. Combine it with the drive directly to the left. (Yes, even if it's a system allocated space). In my case, it's the WINRE partition.
3. Use a third party program to partition the drive, sending the unallocated space to the left side of the drive.
4. Repeat step 3 until the unallocated space is beside the drive you want to extend.
5. Right-click on the drive you want to extend and click on Extend.
6. follow the on screen instructions.

You WILL need a third party program, it can't be done entirely in Disk Management. The one I used for this was EaseUS Free V13.0, it allows you to choose how the disk is partitioned. (you could make very specific partitions, putting the unallocated space on both sides of the original drive, if you needed)
I did, however, need to use Disk Management to do the actual extending, so you may need both if you choose to do it my way.

Hope this helps, good luck.